# Расширенный поиск по БД (универсальный SELECT-запрос)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyqt5, sqlite3

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи. Возникла проблема с созданием универсального SELECT-запроса для расширенного поиска по БД. Суть вопроса заключается в следующем, не могу понять, как выбрать данные по столбцу, если поле для поиска пустое, а значения в столбце присутствуют, т.е. допустим по примеру из примера кода: self.param[4] == '', то выбрать все данные из столбца, или если self.param[4] == 'что-то там', то в общей выборке выдавай только те значения, где есть только "что-то там". Подскажите дельную мысль, или реально надо для каждого случая писать отдельный запрос?

```
elif (self.params[0] != '(не выбрано)' 
      and self.params[1] != '(не выбрано)' 
      and self.params[2] == '(не выбрано)' 
      and self.params[3] == '(не выбрано)' 
      and self.params[4] == '' 
      and self.params[5] == '(не выбрано)'):

self.cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
                       WHERE SomeParam1=:SomeParam1 
                       AND SomeParam2=:SomeParam2''',
                       {'SomeParam1':self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam1.currentText(),
                        'SomeParam2':self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam2.currentText()})  

elif (self.params[0] != '(не выбрано)' 
      and self.params[1] != '(не выбрано)' 
      and self.params[2] != '(не выбрано)' 
      and self.params[3] == '(не выбрано)' 
      and self.params[4] == '' 
      and self.params[5] == '(не выбрано)'):
self.cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
                       WHERE SomeParam1=:SomeParam1
                       AND SomeParam2=:SomeParam2
                       AND SomeParam3=:SomeParam3''',
                       {'SomeParam1':self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam1.currentText(),
                        'SomeParam2':self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam2.currentText(),
                        'SomeParam3':self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam3.currentText()})
```

Comment: См. тему - построение динамических запросов sql.

Comment: @Sergey спасибо, что подсказали где смотреть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разрешил данную проблему таким способом:

во-первых: перевел свою программу на формирование модели и отображении её в QTableView (до этого было QTableWidget);

во-вторых: использовал конструкцию LIKE "{}", если соответственно у нас в форме значение "(не выбрано)", то мы меняем его на "%".

Итого 600+ строк кода уместилось в 12))

```
self.stm.setFilter(('''SomeParam1 LIKE "{0}" 
                       AND SomeParam2 LIKE "{1}"
                       AND SomeParam3 LIKE "{2}"
                       AND SomeParam4 LIKE "{3}"
                       AND SomeParam5 LIKE "{4}"
                       AND SomeParam6 LIKE "%{5}%"
                       ''').format(self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam1.currentText().replace('','%'),
                                   self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam2.currentText().replace('(не выбрано)', '%'),
                                   self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam3.currentText().replace('(не выбрано)', '%'),
                                   self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam4.currentText().replace('(не выбрано)', '%'),
                                   self.ui.comboBoxSomeParam5.currentText().replace('(не выбрано)', '%'),
                                   self.ui.lineEditSomeParam6.text().replace('', '%')))
```